# how can anyone send email to me on my website in js

Tags: javascript, html, email, smtpjs

I am creating a project as I have created a contact page. I want any user to send me a email by putting his email and message in input box of contact page. I have also tried smtpjs but with that I can send the email from my side and registered email on smtpjs but unknown user who put his email without putting his password can't send email to me

for eg-

my email - myemail@gmail.com

my password - mypassword

unknown user email - unknown@gmail.com

how can unknown user send me email by putting only his email on my website contact page

any js library and js code can use for this problem please tell me

Comment: usually handled on your backend code ... do you have the ability for scripting on the backend? or are you just producing a static site?

Answer (score -1):

You should try [emailjs](https://www.emailjs.com/). Just follow the docs [here.](https://www.emailjs.com/docs/)